# File is not a portable executable. DOS header does not contain 'MZ' signature

Tags: dll, decompiler

When i open a Assembly-CSharp.dll in NET Reflector 8.4 from Unity 3D games, it say that the DOS header does not contain 'MZ' Signature. i'm really sure it is C# language. most of Unity 3D games are decompile-able. Can someone help me?

I just want to make some improvements to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about decrypting DLL files from Android apps, you can use GDB core on your rooted device, dump the app, and extract the decrypted DLL file. Follow this tutorial

http://iandrohackerdk.blogspot.dk/2015/11/tutorial-how-to-decrypt-encrypted-dll.html

Comment: thanks. i did it on my rooted android phone and it worked!